# Terminal in Ubuntu not showing directory, instead a check mark and the time stamp

Tags: ubuntu, github, terminal, gitlab, default

I am really really new to Ubuntu. I just created an ssh key for Gitlab from an existing key I am using for Github so that I can create a repository. Then I realized I can just import the one I had on Github, and I did. And now my terminal in Ubuntu looks like this. I don't know what's going on, it doesn't seem to affect anything but I prefer the default one. Can I change it back?

Here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl7xP.png

Edit: Here is my .bashrc file : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TFQq.png

Edit: Yeah the last line that is causing this.

```
source ~/.bash-git-prompt/gitprompt.sh GIT_PROMPT_ONLY_IN_REPO=1
```

I don't know how, but it said I need to have this code on .bashrc after cloning a repository. I really don't want to change my terminal because everything is so overwhelming for now. I was just used to windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably edit your `~/.bashrc` file.
Can you backup your current `~/.bashrc` file and then override its content with the default Ubuntu bashrc file content that you can retrieve from this link:
https://gist.github.com/matt-blodgett/51827068478a6f3e60346fefa49ed576

Comment: Does this reset every variables, paths and aliases that I have set up? I've been adding a lot of those in that file because it is part of the steps when installing some packages.

Comment: @LordDickenstein - You're right that overriding the `bashrc` file will consequently remove your updates. You can try and override PS1 variable in the bashrc file to see if it'll produce the desired results.

Comment: overriding PS1 in .bashrc means I just assign some string to PS1 right? I put PS1="Something" in the .bashrc, it did nothing or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: @LordDickenstein - If you open the link in initial post, you'll see some references to PS1 variable. Can you apply these changes to PS1 variable in your `~/.bashrc` file?

Comment: They're the same thing and nothing happens when I added the block involving PS1. I'll try to delete the content and replace it with the default. I made a back up of it so here I go.

Comment: @LordDickenstein, after making changes to the `~/.bashrc` file, you need to make sure that you source it in your current session so that your changes can be applied to your current session. You can do this with the following command `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Ok now it's back. I just reset it to the default .bashrc and added the new extra lines from when I installed stuffs, except for the last 3 lines of code which I'm sure one of them is causing the problem. I'll just add them one at a time. Thank you so much for giving the time to answer my question. Have a nice day!

Comment: @LordDickenstein - no problem! :)